# How to enable External Objects in Salesforce Developer Edition

Tags: lightning-connect, developer-edition, data-synchronization, etl, winter15

I want to enable External Objects in my developer edition.
How to do it, i was not able to see any settings ?

Comment: Shaik, can you give some more details on what you are after ? what exactly you mean by external objects, and whats your complete requirement / use case ?

Comment: He it looking for that feature https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=67KIFdKshfs - I am not sure exactly, if it parts of it are still in pilot or beta.

Comment: It's hard to find hard evidence, since google brings not up very much about "Salesforce External Objects". I heard about that feature in a breakout session during a Partner Forum in London. As a matter of fact, the setup section does not exist in summer'14 but it does exist in winter'15

Answer (score 2):

**Option A) Use Winter'15 release**

This feature is not available in Summer'14 by default. However it is available in my Preview-Org running Winter'15 release.

[image]

So you need to register a prerelease Org here https://www.salesforce.com/form/signup/prerelease-winter15.jsp

**Option B) On Summer'14 you may try to log a case and ask Salesforce to enable it**

as @RobinDeBondt says in his comment it worked for him, but I haven't verified this.

Comment: I've had it enabled before in one of my orgs (Spring '14), simply by logging a case and asking for the feature activation.